# Does RetroPie's automatic USB ROM transfer copy/overwrite previously copied ROMs?

Tags: pi-3, retropie, data-transfer

If I add a few more ROMs to my USB drive and plug it in, is it going to copy the entire collection again? If so, does it overwrite the files or keep them all? I am using a pi-3 with the latest version of RetroPie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only the files that do not exist on the RetroPie will copy over.**

If the file located on our USB drive is `...roms/nes/Adventure Island.nes` but the file `...roms/nes/Adventure Island.nes` already exists on our RetroPie, it will **not** copy it and it will **not** be overwritten.

If, however, you change the filename to `...roms/nes/Adventure Island (USA).nes` RetroPie **will** copy it, and you **will** have both, simply because the filename is different.

This is the default behavior, and the most logical.

Comment: I answered my own question because I learned how it worked through my own experience. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.